# Secret "Language"?

Tags: cipher

One of my friends gave me a phrase in a 'secret language' to try and solve. This is very urgent as if I solve it, I get a rather great reward. Here is the phrase:

> Hu, E fuh'd. E tu hud fecr du dymg du oui. Ev oui lyh nayt drec, cruja
>   uvv. Ev oui lyh'd, drah cruja uvv. Tuh'd cbayg du sa.

Comment: Seems like [Welsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_language) to me.

Answer (score 31):

The decrypted message is:

> No, I won't. I do not wish to talk to you. If you can read this, shove off. If you can't, then shove off. Don't speak to me.

The cipher is:

> A simple substitution, where every letter of the plaintext is mapped to another letter.
> Many websites exist to solve these types of simple ciphers. Example: http://quipqiup.com/

Comment: @AustinPuckett: If this is the solution (and I believe it is), the reward might not be so great after all, I'm afraid.

Comment: Tryth, I tried the site with O sz rqov and it found 38 solutions. None of which were correct.

Comment: We have a new winner in the "most awkward solve ever" category.

Comment: @warspyking Is it: I am thin ? Only one that made sense from the list using the site, other then I am ship but that would be just weird.

Comment: @Lyrion no it was I am epic.

Comment: @warspyking Ah, if I added the clue r=e then, he could find it at spot 47. But to be fair, there is only one matching letter and that was the o. I'm guessing if the sentence is alot longer then the site will probably find it.

Comment: @Lyrion Tried that too, forget the sentence but it was a lot longer, it still never found it.

Comment: The language is too weak for this cipher to be authentic.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but I wanted to add something to this for those that are interested!

That *is* an actual made up language, it is Al Bhed from the game Final Fantasy 10, the `oui` gives it away, as that's a fairly common word spoken in the game.

I checked and confirmed the same answer as above using an Al Bhed translator. Kinda neat.

Comment: This has already been solved and this doesnt really supply as answer

Comment: I don't see this information in the other solution, +1

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil But it does supply an alternate - and probably the intended - solve path.